# virtual large data reading from log file into a ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, io, virtual

I've been doing some research on how to read large log files, ~500mbs and parse them into a gui using c#. I'm fairly new using virtual mode for listview...

I've decided on using a listbox with virtual mode (hopefully this can handle about 1mil log messages). but I'm having problem reading the lines of the log file into the listbox.

i don't want to read the whole file, because it would crash the program, so im using File.ReadLines in a foreach statement.

I guess I'm having trouble handling the RetrieveVirtualItem handler to read my file, and get a new row and populate it with

```
    private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
          ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.Text = addList(); // need to read a new row
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
        lvsi.Text = e.ItemIndex.ToString("n");
        lvi.SubItems.Add(lvsi);
        e.Item = lvi;
    }
```

how do i read each line of the file and associate it with a virtual retrieval method for listview?

i eventually want to add searching, so it only displays rows in which it hits the matches.

I'm also not sure how to edit the listView1.VirtualListSize - how do i make this a variable that is equal to the amount of matches? i think because it needs a value as i load the form.

Comment: If I had to say one thing, it's that putting 500MB of anything into a GUI control will cause horrible performance issues and loss of stability and responsiveness.  You should find a way to read just a slice of your file at a time.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: hm i agree which is why i want to implement a search function. but im having trouble populating my listview with items corresponding to reading a log file

Comment: Virtual mode listviews are great when viewing huge amount of data.  You should read the file one line at a time and note the position of the start of the line.  Add these positions to a List<int> and.  When RetrieveVirtualItem you should look up the position in the file using the index of the item and the List<int> and then read the line from file.

Comment: @Casperah: Yep thats the way to do it.

Comment: @Casperah It takes about 10s to load the entire file positions into the List<int>, i was thinking about displaying the first 20 - then keep loading while they are displayed. so it doesnt seem like a loading period...would i use a background worker to accomplish this?